# Непредвиденная утечка памяти

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, mfc

Не понимаю что делаю не так. Пытаюсь создать диалог с помощью MFC следующим образом:

Есть пункт меню и диалог(resource.h):

```
...
#define ID_BULK_ADD_DEPEND_CNTRS_MUNU   40056
#define IDD_BULK_ADD_DEPEND_CNTRS       1078
...
```

Которые вот так "присоединяются" (MainFrame.h):

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainFrame,CFrameWnd)
    ...
    ON_COMMAND(ID_BULK_ADD_DEPEND_CNTRS_MUNU,OnBulkAddDependCntrs)
    ...
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

И собственно OnBulkAddDependCntrs определен вот так:

```
void CMainFrame::OnBulkAddDependCntrs()
{
    СBulkAddDependCntrs* ptr_BADC_dialog = new СBulkAddDependCntrs(m_hWnd);
    if (ptr_BADC_dialog != nullptr){
        BOOL ret = ptr_BADC_dialog->Create(ptr_BADC_dialog->IDD, m_hWnd);
        #ifdef _DEBUG
        if (!ret) AfxMessageBox(_T("Error creating СBulkAddDependCntrs (IDD_BULK_ADD_DEPEND_CNTRS)"));
        #endif
        ptr_BADC_dialog->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    }
    #ifdef _DEBUG
    else AfxMessageBox(_T("Error creating object СBulkAddDependCntrs (IDD_BULK_ADD_DEPEND_CNTRS)"));
    #endif
}
```

Определение класса диалога:

```
#pragma once

#include "Resource.h"

// СBulkAddDependCntrs dialog

class СBulkAddDependCntrs : public CDialog
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(СBulkAddDependCntrs)

public:
    СBulkAddDependCntrs(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor
    virtual ~СBulkAddDependCntrs();
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    virtual BOOL Create(UINT nIDTemplate, CWnd *pParent);


// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_BULK_ADD_DEPEND_CNTRS };

protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support


    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

И его реализация:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Counters.h"
#include "BulkAddDependCntrs.h"


// СBulkAddDependCntrs dialog

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(СBulkAddDependCntrs, CDialog)

СBulkAddDependCntrs::СBulkAddDependCntrs(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(СBulkAddDependCntrs::IDD, pParent)
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
    OutputDebugString("СBulkAddDependCntrs::constructer()\n");
#endif
}

СBulkAddDependCntrs::~СBulkAddDependCntrs()
{
}

void СBulkAddDependCntrs::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BOOL СBulkAddDependCntrs::OnInitDialog()
{   
#ifdef _DEBUG
    OutputDebugString("СBulkAddDependCntrs::OnInitDialog()\n");
#endif

    return CDialog::OnInitDialog();
}

BOOL СBulkAddDependCntrs::Create(UINT nIDTemplate, CWnd *pParent)
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
    OutputDebugString("СBulkAddDependCntrs::Create()\n");
#endif

    return CDialog::Create(nIDTemplate, pParent);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(СBulkAddDependCntrs, CDialog)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// СBulkAddDependCntrs message handlers
```

В итоге дебагер пишет что-то такое:

```
СBulkAddDependCntrs::constructer()
СBulkAddDependCntrs::Create()
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{47718} client block at 0x00EE7C58, subtype c0, 116 bytes long.
a СBulkAddDependCntrs object at $00EE7C58, 116 bytes long
{47666} normal block at 0x00EE7848, 42 bytes long.
 Data: <0 H             > 30 82 48 01 19 00 00 00 19 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
{47665} normal block at 0x00EE77F0, 24 bytes long.
 Data: <0 H             > 30 82 48 01 07 00 00 00 07 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
{47664} normal block at 0x00EE7798, 26 bytes long.
 Data: <0 H             > 30 82 48 01 09 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
{47663} normal block at 0x00EE7748, 20 bytes long.
 Data: <0 H             > 30 82 48 01 03 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
{47662} normal block at 0x00EE76F0, 23 bytes long.
 Data: <0 H             > 30 82 48 01 06 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
{47661} normal block at 0x00EE7698, 25 bytes long.
 Data: <0 H             > 30 82 48 01 08 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
{47660} normal block at 0x00EE75F8, 96 bytes long.
 Data: < v  v           > A8 76 EE 00 76 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 CD CD CD 
{39028} normal block at 0x05D50040, 3846392 bytes long.
 Data: <        24805821> C0 D8 04 00 03 00 00 00 32 34 38 30 35 38 32 31 
{277} normal block at 0x00EE8688, 4176 bytes long.
 Data: <                > F2 FD E4 E3 00 FE FE FE D2 E5 EF EB EE FD ED E5 
{242} normal block at 0x00EE7598, 30 bytes long.
 Data: <0 H             > 30 82 48 01 0D 00 00 00 0D 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
{241} normal block at 0x00EE7530, 42 bytes long.
 Data: <0 H             > 30 82 48 01 19 00 00 00 19 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
{240} normal block at 0x00EE74D8, 26 bytes long.
 Data: <0 H             > 30 82 48 01 09 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
{239} normal block at 0x00EE7480, 23 bytes long.
 Data: <0 H             > 30 82 48 01 06 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
{238} normal block at 0x00EE7428, 26 bytes long.
 Data: <0 H             > 30 82 48 01 09 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
{237} normal block at 0x00EE73D0, 25 bytes long.
 Data: <0 H             > 30 82 48 01 08 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
{236} normal block at 0x00EE2550, 18 bytes long.
 Data: <0 H             > 30 82 48 01 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
{235} normal block at 0x00EE24B0, 96 bytes long.
 Data: <`%              > 60 25 EE 00 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 CD CD CD 
{234} normal block at 0x00EE2468, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <        > 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
{232} normal block at 0x00EE7380, 20 bytes long.
 Data: <0 H             > 30 82 48 01 03 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
{231} normal block at 0x00EE7328, 21 bytes long.
 Data: <0 H             > 30 82 48 01 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
{230} normal block at 0x00EE72D8, 20 bytes long.
 Data: <0 H             > 30 82 48 01 03 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
{229} normal block at 0x00EE25A0, 21 bytes long.
 Data: <0 H             > 30 82 48 01 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
{225} normal block at 0x00EE2328, 100 bytes long.
 Data: <    @           > 00 00 00 00 40 01 00 00 00 01 00 08 00 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\plex.cpp(29) : {224} normal block at 0x00EE2210, 124 bytes long.
 Data: <             q  > 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 71 EE 00 
{221} normal block at 0x00EE2080, 25 bytes long.
 Data: <0 H             > 30 82 48 01 08 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
.\CountersApp.cpp(250) : {220} client block at 0x00EE6F70, subtype c0, 808 bytes long.
a CFrameWnd object at $00EE6F70, 808 bytes long
{219} normal block at 0x00EE22D0, 23 bytes long.
 Data: <0 H             > 30 82 48 01 06 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
{81} normal block at 0x00EE6F20, 20 bytes long.
 Data: <0 H             > 30 82 48 01 03 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 
{65} normal block at 0x00EE1C90, 21 bytes long.
 Data: <0 H             > 30 82 48 01 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
{64} normal block at 0x00EE1C30, 29 bytes long.
 Data: <                > C0 D0 CC 20 E4 EB FF 20 F0 E0 E1 EE F2 FB 20 F1 
Object dump complete.
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xcb0) has exited with code 3 (0x3).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1138) has exited with code 3 (0x3).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xc68) has exited with code 3 (0x3).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x5b8) has exited with code 3 (0x3).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x568) has exited with code 3 (0x3).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1820) has exited with code 3 (0x3).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1354) has exited with code 3 (0x3).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1abc) has exited with code 3 (0x3).
The program '[6252] Counters.exe: Native' has exited with code 3 (0x3).
```

Что соответствует, на сколько я понимаю, тому, что объект создался, но вызов Creatу() приводит к утечке памяти.

Естественно никакого диалогового окна не открывается.

Впервые столкнулся с MFC. Есть какие-либо идеи, как решить проблему?

Answer (score 2):

СBulkAddDependCntrs* ptr_BADC_dialog = new СBulkAddDependCntrs(m_hWnd); 
Ты сделал new, в конце должен удалить динамически созданный объект, желательно с проверкой

```
if (ptr_BADC_dialog !=nullptr)
{
   delete ptr_BADC_dialog;
   ptr_BADC_dialog = nullptr;
}
```